# meaning of protected static A.B newvar = null

Tags: java

I was going throught a huge java project and I came across this line in a file.I am new to java and don't know what this means.Or more specifically

Should I look at PSStreamer.java OR Client.java to see the methods and member variables of the below object.

```
protected static PSStreamer.Client packetClient = null;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what's being declared:

```
protected            // protected visibility modifier
static               // a class (static) member
PSStreamer.Client    // Client is an inner class of PSStreamer
packetClient = null; // variable name, null initial value
```

You should look inside `PSStreamer` to find the inner class `Client`, and that's where you'll find the attributes and methods of `packetClient`.

Answer (score 2):

That is a [*static inner class*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

It would look like this: (in PSStreamer.java):

```
class PSStreamer {
    ...
    static class Client {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Static class is not an inner-class. They're just nested.

Answer (score 1):

That is a *static nested* class. It should be defined in the source code as

```
public class PSStreamer {

  public static class Client {
    // ..
  }
  // ..
}
```

So, you should be looking inside `PSStreamer.java`. Read more about [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

> Nested classes that are declared static are simply called static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes.

Also, take a look at this SO link: [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)